# SQL: How to get relational data from two tables? (Using JOIN ?)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been experimenting with doing some cross relational SQL queries, without success so far.  Wondering if anyone can help?

I have two tables of interest and am trying to find out which of my customers (=company contact 1) have to do items outstanding.  Here's the table sturcture:

```
TABLE: CUSTOMERS

ID    |    CUSTOMER_NAME    |    COMPANY_CONTACT
=================================================
1           Bob                     1
2           Billy                   2
3           Susan                   2
4           Ryan                    3
5           Sally                   1
```

.

```
TABLE: TO_DOS
ID    |    TASK         |    CUSTOMER_ID
============================================
1          Make Tea                 5
2          Pick flowers             1
3          Do invoices              3
4          Tidy up                  4
5          Drive van                2
```

The ideal output would be

```
CUSTOMER_ID     |   CUSTOMER_NAME  |  TASK
=================================================================
5           Sally         Make Tea
1           Bob           Pick flowers
```

So far I've tried this but it's not getting me anywhere:

```
SELECT * FROM TO_DOS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUSTOMERS.COMPANY_CONTACT=1
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are putting this relationship in a join then use INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON <Criteria>, else you are doing a full join and limiting the results to company contact 1.

Comment: Thanks @lrb, do you have any good links of where I read about how inner join and on work. I think I was on the right lines, but not quite there! Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.ID, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NAME, TO-DOS.TASK 
FROM TO_DOS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON TO_DOS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE CUSTOMERS.COMPANY_CONTACT = 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!  Do you have any good links of where I read about how `inner join` and `on` work.  I think I was on the right lines, but not quite there!  Thanks again :-)

Comment: Actually if you Google ***SQL JOIN Tutorial*** you will find a ton of information explaining how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TO_DOS AS A
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS B ON A.CUSTOMER_ID=B.ID
WHERE CUSTOMERS.COMPANY_CONTACT=1
```

The company contact number will determine which customer is selected so if you would like to select Sally and Bob you would choose 1.

Comment: Will `CUSTOMERS.COMPANY_CONTACT=1` work? You may require `B.COMPANY_CONTACT=1`