# Join specific attributes from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to create a database. In the database I need to join only specific attributes from my Software table to the SiteKey in my LicenceSchema table. I've looked around online and can't find anything on joining specific attributes from a table to another in the other table. Database class has been really confusing me and I struggle to understand just by reading about it. So I have this LicenceSchema table
[image]

and this Software table
[image]

Software has 15 different softwares listed in it and I need to take 9 of them (Eclipse, HTML-Kit, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, JGrasp, Android Studio, Raptor, Linux) and join them with the SiteKey in LicenceSchema

If someone could help me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How to get relational data from two tables? (Using JOIN ?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644252/sql-how-to-get-relational-data-from-two-tables-using-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

Eclipse, HTML-Kit, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, JGrasp, Android Studio, Raptor, Linux

So I made the following assumption: name from the one table is in a list, and the join is on like named columns.

### Schema

```
create table LicenceSchema 
(   SchemaID int auto_increment primary key,
    SiteKey varchar(45) not null,
    CopyKey varchar(45) not null,
    StrictKey varchar(45) not null,
    Software_SoftwareID int not null,
    Software_College_CollegeID int not null
);

create table Software
(   SoftwareID int auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(45) not null,
    College_CollegeID int not null
);
```

### Query

```
select s.*,l.*
from Software s
join LicenceSchema l
on l.Software_SoftwareID=s.SoftwareID
where s.Name in ('Eclipse', 'HTML-Kit', 'Internet Explorer', 'Chrome', 'Firefox', 'JGrasp', 'Android Studio', 'Raptor', 'Linux');
```

`s` and `l` are just aliases. Select * is not a great idea in general. So prune down the select list to just the columns you want. Such as

```
select s.SoftwareID, s.Name, s.College_CollegeID ,l.SchemaID, l.SchemaID
...
```

Comment: Now there are other types of Licence types in LicenceSchema. I have SiteKey, CopyKey, and StrictKey. Won't this assign these pieces of software to all of them? I have other software that needs to be assigned to the other Licence types.

Comment: all I can go by is what you are showing. And if you are going to show more, do it with text output. Such as that shown by `show create table xxx`